# Handling inner class exceptions in custom exception class java

Tags: java, exception

I am working through a java textbook, and for one of the programs I have to write I have to handle my custom exceptions while converting standard time to military time. I used inner classes to handle the three classes in one file. I am not 100% sure this works, I haven't found anything that says it wont, or anything that says it will so far. I am probably making this way harder than it needs to be, but the book says I need the three classes with their specific names.

I have tried following what the IDE tells me, it says *No enclosing instance of type InvalidTimeException is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type InvalidTimeException (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of InvalidTimeException).* To me this tells me to put `throws new InvalidTimeException.new InvalidHrException();` this doesn't work. SO I tried setting it up like this `throws new InvalidTimeException(new InvalidHrException)`

**Exception Class**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InvalidTimeException extends Exception {

    public InvalidTimeException () {
        System.out.println("Unknown Time error: An error has occoured in the program... shutting down.");
    }

    public InvalidTimeException (String var) {
        System.out.println("Input Mismatch Exception: \"" + var + "\" is not a number.");
    }

    public class InvalidHrException extends Exception {
        public InvalidHrException () {
            System.out.println("Error in hour input: An error has occoured with the hour input");
        }
    }

    public class InvalidMinException extends Exception {
        public InvalidMinException () {
            System.out.println("Error in minute input: An error has occoured with the minute input");
        }
    }

    public class InvalidSecException extends Exception {
        public InvalidSecException () {
            System.out.println("Error in seconds input: An error has occoured with the seconds input");
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Method**

```java
public static void hourChecker (int var) throws InvalidHrException, InvalidTimeException {
        if (var <= 0) {
            throw new InvalidTimeException(new InvalidHrException());
        }
    }
```

I would expect this to let me throw the exception of the inner class InvalidHrException, from the InvalidTimeException class. However no matter what I try there seems to be an error. I am not sure if I just over complicated things or what. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

*current code to make error classes work*

```
public InvalidTimeException (InvalidHrException IHE) throws InvalidHrException {
        // just lets the program hit the inner classes
    }
```

*current example method*

```
public static void hourChecker (int var) throws InvalidHrException, InvalidTimeException {
        if (var <= 0 || var > 12) {
            throw new InvalidTimeException.InvalidHrException();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably need a static inner class.

Comment: Related question: [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Comment: Omg thank you that did it, wow I feel kinda dumb now. I will probably just delete this because it was that simple. Thnaks though I am pretty sure you'll still see this.

Comment: @glee8e So upon further inspection that doesn't really work the way I want it. It made me create a constructor in the error class that had all of the inner classes as parameters. So It works but in a roundabout way that doesn't feel right. Is there another way to do this? I am honestly only pursuing this because I am learning now, I should learn the right way. I'll add an edit right now to show you what I currently have to make it work.

Comment: It looks like what you really need is use `InvalidTimeException` as an abstract base class and let the `InvalidHrException` and its friends to be the subclass of that base class. `InvalidHrException` can still be a static inner class within that base class if you desire.